# Tools for Cordova CTP3 connect etimedout when building

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013

I've created a Apache Cordova Project and trying to build it as it is. Visual Studio keeps failing on the same step all the time:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\name\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\V4GFNZQH.M4F\packages\vs-mda
1>MDAVSCLI : error : connect ETIMEDOUT
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And the output window shows:

```
Error   2   connect ETIMEDOUT   C:\Users\name\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\MDAVSCLI   1   1   Test
```

I've tried on two computers, reinstalling npm completely, "manually" installing the stuff in the folder but with the same error. I must be doing something wrong, what?

Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 Tools for Cordova CTP3.

EDIT:

```
  Task "RunMdaTargetsInstall" (TaskId:9)
1>  Task Parameter:MdaVsixDir=C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\V4GFNZQH.M4F (TaskId:9)
1>  Task Parameter:NodeInstallPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\ (TaskId:9)
1>  Task Parameter:LangName=en-US (TaskId:9)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectDir=. (TaskId:9)
1>  Task Parameter:Configuration=Debug (TaskId:9)
1>  C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  (TaskId:9)
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm. (TaskId:9)
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\V4GFNZQH.M4F\packages\vs-mda (TaskId:9)
1>Done executing task "RunMdaTargetsInstall". (TaskId:9)
1>Task "CallTarget" (TaskId:10)
1>  Task Parameter:Targets=MDACleanAfterInstall (TaskId:10)
1>Target "MDACleanAfterInstall: (TargetId:13)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\Test.jsproj" (target "InstallMDATargets" depends on it):
1>Task "CallTarget" (TaskId:11)
1>  Task Parameter:Targets=CleanCordovaDeploy (TaskId:11)
1>Target "CleanCordovaDeploy: (TargetId:14)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\Test.jsproj" (target "MDACleanAfterInstall" depends on it):
1>Using "RemoveDir" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "RemoveDir" (TaskId:12)
1>  Task Parameter:Directories=C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin (TaskId:12)
1>  Directory "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin" doesn't exist. Skipping. (TaskId:12)
1>Done executing task "RemoveDir". (TaskId:12)
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (@(CordovaDeployDirs) != @(DeletedDirectories)) was evaluated as (C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin != C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\CordovaDeploy\CordovaDeploy\bin).
1>Done building target "CleanCordovaDeploy" in project "Test.jsproj".: (TargetId:14)
1>Done executing task "CallTarget". (TaskId:11)
1>Using "CreateItem" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "CreateItem" (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:Include=C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\**\* (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:Exclude=C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Ripple\Android\Debug\JsFileList.JSON (TaskId:13)
1>Done executing task "CreateItem". (TaskId:13)
1>Using "Delete" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Delete" (TaskId:14)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Files=
1>          C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Android\Debug\changeList.json
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\**\*
1>                  RecursiveDir=Android\Debug\ (TaskId:14)
1>  Task Parameter:TreatErrorsAsWarnings=True (TaskId:14)
1>  Deleting file "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\\bld\Android\Debug\changeList.json". (TaskId:14)
1>Done executing task "Delete". (TaskId:14)
1>Task "RemoveDir" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists('%(Identity)')) was evaluated as (Exists('')).
1>Done building target "MDACleanAfterInstall" in project "Test.jsproj".: (TargetId:13)
1>Done executing task "CallTarget". (TaskId:10)
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '0' And $(MDAInstallErrorCode) != '-17') was evaluated as (-17 != '0' And -17 != '-17').
1>Done building target "InstallMDATargets" in project "Test.jsproj".: (TargetId:12)
1>Done executing task "CallTarget". (TaskId:8)
1>Done building target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" in project "Test.jsproj".: (TargetId:11)
1>Target "BuildMDA: (TargetId:15)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets" from project "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\Test.jsproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ($(Platform) == 'iOS' AND $(iOSRemoteBuildSecurityPIN) == 'NULL') was evaluated as (Android == 'iOS' AND  == 'NULL').
1>Using "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" (TaskId:15)
1>  Task Parameter:TargetPath=bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml (TaskId:15)
1>  Task Parameter:OutputFormat=Xml (TaskId:15)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      BuildInfoMetadata=
1>          VisualStudio
1>                  Version=12.0
1>          VisualStudioEdition
1>                  Value=Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
1>          C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
1>                  Name=OperatingSystem
1>          ProjectGUID
1>                  Value=42f23701-8b18-4691-b076-76bf6734d822 (TaskId:15)
1>Done executing task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata". (TaskId:15)
1>Task "CreateBuildInfoMetadata" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>Task "ExportRemoteIosCertificates" skipped, due to false condition; ($(Platform) == 'iOS' AND $(iOSRemoteBuildSecurityPIN) != '') was evaluated as (Android == 'iOS' AND  != '').
1>Task "MdaVsCli" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(BuildMDACpuSpecificPlatform)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).
1>Using "MdaVsCli" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>Task "MdaVsCli" (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:VsCliPath= C:\Users\Ludvig\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli.cmd (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:Platform=Android (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectDir=. (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:Configuration=Debug (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectName=Test (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:Language=en-US (TaskId:16)
1>  Task Parameter:BuildTarget=AndroidEmulator (TaskId:16)
1>  ------ Build Settings: (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    buildCommand: build (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    platform: Android (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    configuration: Debug (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    projectName: Test (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator (TaskId:16)
1>  ------    language: en-US (TaskId:16)
1>  ------ Creating app at C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\bld\Debug (TaskId:16)
1>  Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hellocordova" at location "C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\bld\Debug" (TaskId:16)
1>  Using stock cordova hello-world application. (TaskId:16)
1>  Requesting {"url":"https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-app-hello-world.git;a=snapshot;h=3.6.3;sf=tgz","strictSSL":true}... (TaskId:16)
1>  Downloading cordova library for www... (TaskId:16)
1>MDAVSCLI : error : connect ETIMEDOUT
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:16)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "Test.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:15)
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>    21849 ms  C:\Users\Ludvig\Documents\GitHub\Test\Test\Test.jsproj   1 calls
1>              21849 ms  build                                      1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanCordovaDeploy                         1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
1>        1 ms  CompileTypeScript                          2 calls
1>        2 ms  MDACleanAfterInstall                       1 calls
1>        4 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>        4 ms  TrackJsChanges                             1 calls
1>      112 ms  InstallMDATargets                          1 calls
1>      113 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
1>    21726 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  Message                                    3 calls
1>        0 ms  RemoveDir                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  Delete                                     1 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignTargetPath                           1 calls
1>        1 ms  MdaTrackJsChanges                          1 calls
1>        1 ms  VsTsc                                      1 calls
1>        2 ms  CreateItem                                 1 calls
1>        9 ms  CreateBuildInfoMetadata                    1 calls
1>      110 ms  RunMdaTargetsInstall                       1 calls
1>      114 ms  CallTarget                                 3 calls
1>    21716 ms  MdaVsCli                                   1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:21.84
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Getting the same error when trying to create a cordova project with CMD. I've tried turning the Windows firewall off and running cmd as Admin.

Most stuff I find on internet is for proxy users but I'm not using one.

Comment: To help diagnose the issue better, please set your build output to diagnostic (Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run\MSBuild project build output verbosity), do a clean build, and post the resulting output starting from build task  "RunMdaTargetsInstall" until the end.

Comment: Also, check your network connectivity and firewall settings.  It needs to install a whole bunch of node packages and requires network connectivity for that.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've updated the post with the new information.

Comment: The ETIMEDOUT error is happening accessing the www library that Cordova downloads during first build.  It's cached so it only needs to download once, but you do need an internet connection during the first build.  There must be something blocking your access.

Answer (score 1):

When VS compiles code first time Cordova will try to connect to GitHub and load additional packages. If you are are using proxy, then you need to configure machine so Cordova will use proxy to connect to GitHub. What you need to do is to set **HTTP_PROXY** environment variable to your proxy.

> HTTP_PROXY=http://your_proxy:8080

However if your proxy requires user name and password then set your proxy to

> HTTP_PROXY=http://user_name:your_password@your_proxy:8080

In case if you need to specify domain name for user you will have to you will have to encode url-encode \ with '%5C' so it will look like

> HTTP_PROXY=http://mydomain%5Cuser_name:your_password@your_proxy:8080

After compiling first time you can remove that environment variable.
Please remember after setting environment variable you will have to restart VS so it pickups changes.

Comment: How do you specify a windows domain name for the user? Trying: `npm --global config set proxy http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassord@myproxyserver:8080` still doesn't work

Comment: I updated my answer with information for domain name. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue but I finally figured it out. In visual studio under tools/options expand "Tools for Apache Cordova" under Remote Agent Configuration change your Host entry to have the ipv4 IP address of your mac.

This was the fix for us